# Can I integrate the facebook messenger into a native app?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

I am trying to use the facebook messenger bot feature without leaving my app (ios/android) and without needing to code my own chat which supports all the messenger features (tiles to choose answers etc.)

Is there any possibility to have the user chat with someone on facebook without the need to use the actual messenger app?